# Verificar Data de criação de arquivo e excluir

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, datetime

Criei um aplicativo de Backup, ele salva os arquivos em zip no formato `DD-MM-YYY - 00-00-00.zip`, porém gostaria de saber como eu faria pra fazer a verificação de data de criação para exclusão, pois o nome dos arquivos são distintos por salvar até os segundos.

Eu deveria verificar pelo diretório dos arquivos?
Código para identificação da criação:

`DateTime data = Directory.GetCreationTime(diretorio);`

O funcionamento deve ser, se a data de criação é superior a 10 dias por exemplo excluí-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei algumas respostas que podem lhe ajudar.

[Resposta do Steve Danner no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222400/221800):

```
using System.IO; 

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);

foreach (string file in files) {
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
   if (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
      fi.Delete();
}
```

[Resposta do Uri Abramson no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17475145/221800):

```
Directory.GetFiles(dirName)
     .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
     .Where(f => f.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(f => f.Delete());
```

[Resposta mais completinha do Adriano Repetti no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295660/221800):

```
static class Helpers {
    public static void DeleteOldFiles(string folderPath, uint maximumAgeInDays, params string[] filesToExclude) {
        DateTime minimumDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-maximumAgeInDays);
        foreach (var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)) {
            if (IsExcluded(path, filesToExclude))
                continue;

            DeleteFileIfOlderThan(path, minimumDate);
        }
    }

    private const int RetriesOnError = 3;
    private const int DelayOnRetry = 1000;

    private static bool IsExcluded(string item, string[] exclusions) {
        foreach (string exclusion in exclusions) {
            if (item.Equals(exclusion, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool DeleteFileIfOlderThan(string path, DateTime date) {
        for (int i = 0; i < RetriesOnError; ++i) {
            try {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
                if (file.CreationTime < date)
                    file.Delete();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry);
            } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Tem mais [algumas aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720790/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/FilterDate.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pela correção bigown.